# How to find JavaScript function called when clicking an anchor in HTML

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I am just wondering in Twitter, when you click "replay" of a tweet, what front-end function is called. I inspected the element in Chrome and it seems to be an anchor with `href="#"`, so I guess there is some JavaScript function associated with the `onclick` event of that anchor. Just wondering how to find out which function is called and where is the source code of that function?

Here is the code part of the "replay" on Twitter:

```
<a class="with-icn js-action-reply" data-modal="tweet-reply" href="#" title="Reply">
<i class="sm-reply"></i>
<b>Reply</b>
</a>
```

Comment: Just look through their javascript for `js-action-reply`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their script is minified, so it's kind of impossible to look at. However there are two things you can do:

- Use Chrome's Event Listener Breakpoints to break into the debugger when you click  the reply link
- Like MrOBrian said: search their scripts for js-action-reply

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data('events')`, try the following:

```
console.log($('.js-action-reply').data('events'))
```

Comment: That's only if there's a separate handler per reply link, which is unlikely

Comment: I just tried this and on my Chrome console, the output is two lines of "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You need the built-in 'Profiling' tab in chrome.

What you can do with it:
1) You can select the time boundary to view the function calls.
If you click on a function name, chrome will directly take you to the function's body!!
Flame chart explained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0g4ML4nhPg

[Flame chart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNK0G.jpg)